# Trouble labeling an angle within a picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

My tikz does not want to label the angle within the figure. Whenever I try to use the command "$\alpha$" inside the pic arguments tikz ignores it. I do not know how to proceed. Any suggestions for the code are welcome. Thank you for the help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (5.46,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below:\(A\)] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=below:\(B\)] (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate [label=above:\(C\)] (C) at (5.46,2);
\coordinate [label=above:\(D\)] (D) at (0,2);
\coordinate [label=left:\(2\)] (E) at (0,1);
\coordinate [label=below:\(2\)] (F) at (1,0);
\coordinate (G) at (3.5,0);
\draw[dashed] (2,0) -- (3.5,0);
\draw (G) -- (B) -- (C)
pic [draw=black, thick, angle radius=1cm, "$\alpha$"] {angle=G--B--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see the label when I compile your code. Do you not see the `\alpha` in the picture?

Comment: @Alenanno No. It accuses 16 errors "as missing \endcsname". I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Does ***precisely the code you posted*** give an error when you copy-paste it into a new, empty `.tex` file and compile? I'm betting not. We need an example we can reproduce the issue with. However, as a guess: in your real document (which does give the error), try adding `babel` to the list of TikZ libraries you are loading.

Comment: @cfr It fixed it! What changes does babel introduce?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly because you've not provided the code required to reproduce the problem. I assume you are loading `babel` with a language and using active short hands, presumably including the `"`. The TikZ library works around the problems this otherwise causes.